# Is there a command line tool for analyzing audio frequency

Tags: command-line, audio, streaming

I am planning to analyze audio via linux command line.
There are a lot of analyzers out there which have a graphical interface, but since I want to make an automated input/output of this information I can't use a GUI.

The optimal case would be to send an audiostream from an embedded device to powerful machine, which analyzes the audio and then generates a csv or db entries with the data and builds some graphs out of it for a website.

If there so no such thing for audiostreams, an analyzer for audiofiles will also be a great step forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line batch audio processing tools are `sox`(http://sox.sourceforge.net/) and `ecasound`(http://www.eca.cx/ecasound/). You may want to check `man soxformat` for the list of supported formats (i.e. streaming and file formats). It may be also beneficial to consider including `ffmpeg`(see http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) into the toolchain for conversion from some of the exotic codecs into mainstream formats.